# Exim: Add X-Report-Abuse: TEXT to report abuse Headers

Tags: exim4

I am using Exim and Dovecot.
I want add to all outgoing email an anti-abuse header like:

X-Report-Abuse: TEXT to report abuse

How I can do this?
Thanks in advance

Thanks, this is not helping me.
I added the line where you told but also incoming email have the X-Report-Abuse heder.

I cannot find that on my Exim

```
send_to_gateway:
```

I added the `headers_add = X-Report-Abuse: TEXT to report abuse` here:

## This transport is used for delivering messages over SMTP connections.

```
remote_smtp:
      driver = smtp 
      dkim_domain = ${lc:${domain:$h_from:}} 
      dkim_selector = x 
      dkim_private_key = /etc/exim/dkim.private.key 
      dkim_canon = relaxed
      headers_add = X-Report-Abuse: Please report any abuse text
```

this is working if the outgoing email are sent from an email client, is not working if email is sent by SMTP from a PHP script or app like wordpress or other PHP app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This adds a header to outgoing messages:**

Add this line to your `exim.conf` file within your outgoing router(s) configuration:

```
headers_add = X-Report-Abuse: TEXT to report abuse
```

**For example**

```
begin routers

...

send_to_gateway:
  driver = manualroute
  domains = !+local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
  route_list = * smtp.myisp.net
  headers_add = X-Report-Abuse: TEXT to report abuse

dnslookup:
  driver = dnslookup
  domains = ! +local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
  ignore_target_hosts = 0.0.0.0 : 127.0.0.0/8
  headers_add = X-Report-Abuse: TEXT to report abuse
  no_more
```

Comment: Jim thank you so much! After a lot of time finally I am able to add this to my emails. Never found a solution in a very long time. Your response is very clear and easy to understand. Many, many thanks!

Comment: Sorry this is not solving the issue fully: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49571438/x-report-abuse-on-mail-sent-from-smtp-php I was also unable to understand how to reply to you here so I opened a new topic as comment are limited